# How to resize many Circles on user map zoom?

Tags: java, android

I'm drawing many circles on Google Maps API with the following code:

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                    .center(lastKnownLatLng)
                                    .radius(4)
                                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                                    .fillColor(Color.RED));
```

And store them into `List<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>()` by adding them one by one with `circleList.add(circle)`.
I want to make the radius of these circles resizing automatically when the user zoom "in" and "out" (like Polyline Class do). This is my solution but I have no idea how to calculate new radius.

```
public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener() {
        return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                Log.d("Zoom", "Zoom: " + position.zoom);
                zoomLevel = position.zoom;
                if(!circleList.isEmpty()){
                    resizeCircles();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void resizeCircles() {
        if (???) { // if zoom in, it mean zoomLevel increase and I need to decrease radius
            double newRadius = ???

            for (int i = 0; i < circleList.size(); i++)
                circleList.get(i).setRadius(newRadius);
        }

        if (???) { // if zoom out, it mean zoomLevel decrease and I need to increase radius
            double newRadius = ???

            for (int i = 0; i < circleList.size(); i++)
                circleList.get(i).setRadius(newRadius);
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you calculate newRadius?

Answer (score 0):

## Original Answer

Figure out the default radius when not zoomed. Then use the zoom level as a multiplier to your initial radius.

You might also want to change your circle's initial radius to a constant so it can be used elsewhere. Adjust this value as needed for your app.

```
private static final double INITIAL_RADIUS = 4.0;
```

Instead of depending on the previous zoom level, find the current zoom level so you can then determine an appropriate multiplier. When increasing the zoom level by 1, it doubles the width of the view, so we'd want to have similar behavior for the circle radius.

```
// Something like this, perhaps.
double newRadius = INITIAL_RADIUS * Math.pow(2.0, currentZoomLevel);
```

Zoom level 0 is also a possibility, so this may be a special case to deal with.

More about the zoom levels can be found here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom

## Extended Answer

Decreasing the circle size when zooming in is just the inverse. An adjustment to the initial radius may be necessary. Again, be aware of the 0 zoom level possibility.

```
// Something like this, perhaps.
double newRadius = INITIAL_RADIUS / Math.pow(2.0, currentZoomLevel);
```

Comment: the problem is that circle could also decrease depending on zooming!

Comment: If you zoom in or out, the circle radius will expand when closer and constrict when farther. Is this not the behavior you're looking for? That's what I assumed from the original question.

Comment: zoom in (getting closer to a point) -> decrease circle to fit it well.
zoom out -> increase circle to make it more visible

Comment: I have edited my pseudo code to make it more understandable